# SQL Server 2012 UPDATE REPLACE with 2 columns from another table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update a column in one table (#TEMPTABLE) using data in another table (#PEOPLE) by using the REPLACE() function.

#TEMPTABLE has a column called "NameString' that is a long string with a user's name and ID.

#PEOPLE has a column for ID, and IDnumber.

```
UPDATE #TEMPTABLE
SET NAMEString = REPLACE(NAMEString, a.[ID], a.[IDNumber]) FROM #PEOPLE a
```

I'm trying to replace all the ID's in the NameString Column with the IDnumbers coming from #People table.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not how you should ask question. anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give it a join criterion.  For example:

```
update #TEMPTABLE
set NAMEString = replace(a.NAMEString, a.ID, b.IDNumber) 
from #TEMPTABLE a
left join #PEOPLE b
on a.id = b.ID
```

Also, make sure to reference the right table when you use the `IDNumber` column - your original query doesn't actually use the table containing `IDNumber` at all, as far as I can tell from your description of your tables.

Note that my example assumes there's an `ID` field in `#TempTable`, or something else to join on - otherwise, you may need to extract it from the `NameString` column first.